# Select default value in dropdown Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to set default values in select.

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "teachers/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

    $('.qual_id option[value=' + data.qualifs + ']').attr('selected', true);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
      $qualifs = DB::table('qualif_teachers')
      ->join ('qualifs','qualif_teachers.qualif_id','=','qualifs.id')
      ->where('teacher_id', '=' , $id)
      ->pluck('qualifs.id');

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'qualifs'=> $qualifs,
        ]);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control qual_id">
    <option value="">-Select Degree-</option>
    <option value="1">SSC</option>
    <option value="2">HSC</option>
    <option value="3">BBA</option>
    <option value="4">MBA</option>
</select>
```

**Error:**

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .qual_id option[value=1,2]

Comment: Please capture the ajax response from your success function: function (data) { alert(data); } and add it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being specific about the javascript framework you're using and without knowing the format of your ajax response,  this  works (assuming that `defaultValue` holds your desired option value):

```
var defaultValue = 1

$(`.qual_id option[value=${defaultValue}]`).attr('selected', true);
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandamasri/2uhmreo5/5/).

Comment: Yes it does work (see my linked fiddle).  What is the format of the ajax response data?  You need to parse the ajax response and inject the desired option value into defaultValue.

Comment: got it, how can i select same code for multiple select?

Comment: Thanks it worked, i am curious if it is possible for multiple select too.